# Is it good solution to use checked decorator function in Stream API?

Tags: java, function, exception, lambda, java-stream

I'm using Java 8 Stream API, and as we know it doesn't supports checked exceptions inside any functional interface inside java.util.function.

I usually have to use method with checked exceptions inside streams operations and I've wrote CheckedFunction decorator to use inside those operations:

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Function;

public interface CheckedFunction<T, R, E extends Throwable> {

    R apply(T t) throws E;

    static <T, R, CE extends Throwable, UCE extends RuntimeException> Function<T, R> checked(
            CheckedFunction<T, R, CE> checked, Function<CE, UCE> exceptionHandler) {
        return (t) -> {
            try {
                return checked.apply(t);
            }
            catch (RuntimeException | Error e) {
                throw e;
            }
            catch (Throwable e) {
                // can't catch - compiler error
                if (e instanceof InterruptedException) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                throw exceptionHandler.apply((CE) e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

so I can use it in such cases:

```
entities.stream()
        .map(checked((entity) -> someResultChecked(entity), // throws IOException
                     (entity, e) -> { // e is of type IOException
                         log.error("exception during checked method of " + entity, e);
                         return new UncheckedIOException(e);
                     }))
        .map(checked((entity) -> saveToDb(entity), // throws SQLException
                     (entity, e) -> { // e is of type SQLException
                         log.error("exception during saving " + entity, e);
                         return new UncheckedSQLException(e);
                     }))
        .map(checked((entity) -> manyExceptionMethod(entity), // throws IOException, SQLException
                     (entity, e) -> { // e is of type Throwable
                         return new RuntimeException(e);
                     }))
```

It will wrap any checked exception to unchecked, but I know if method is throws more than one exception it will erase to Throwable, I'm going to use it in simple cases.

Is it good idea, or I can run into hidden obstacles?

**UPDATED:** Rethrowing RuntimeExceptions.

Also I found more clear solution in jOOL with handling InterruptedException which can cause inconsistent behavior if will be ignored:
https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jooq/lambda/Unchecked.java

Comment: You should take a look at JavaRx which provides a nice API for streaming with error handling

Comment: Thanks, I tried to look into several times, but always gave up.Maybe it's a signal that I need to sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

You'll get a `ClassCastException` if anything other than an `IOException` gets thrown, since you're catching all `Throwable` and passing them into the `UncheckedIOException` constructor, which only takes an `IOException` as a parameter.  Since catching `IOException` within a functional type is such a common need, rather than trying to generalize, it may be best to keep it simple and make one just for that checked exception. I would imagine you would rarely need to duplicate code to do the same for other checked exceptions.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CheckedIOFunction<T,R> {

    R apply(T t) throws IOException;

    static <T, R> Function<T, R> toUnchecked(CheckedIOFunction<T, R> function) {
        return t -> {
            try {
                return function.apply(t);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(ioe);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really, <CE> infers from method I use. So if I will use method that throws IOException it will be <CE extends IOException> and in exceptionHandler you will get e of type IOException, and if it's throws anything else e will be of it's type (or of type Throwable if there are will be multiple exceptions). For example you can run example and see output https://gist.github.com/gavlyukovskiy/30e28bae4b572b5a67c3a7c432069f46

Comment: That's an interesting idea.  Are there any final exception types that are commonly thrown?

Comment: Commonly we are using only single exception, so it can be handled with it's unchecked analog. Or we frequently throwing UserApiException to indicate user request problem.

Comment: @Monk3D: `CE` can be inferred to a checked exception declared by the target method and, indeed, the target method can’t throw other checked exceptions. Still, `catch(Throwable)` will also catch all *unchecked* exceptions, i.e. `RuntimeException`s and `Error`s, so this answer has a point. The correct solution would be to sort them out before: `catch(RuntimeException|Error unchecked) { throw unchecked; } catch(Throwable checkedException) { throw exceptionHandler.apply(t, (CE)checkedException); }` But note that the resulting requirement that `CE` must be a checked exception can’t be expressed.

Comment: @Holger, Thanks, I updated the answer. I'm not fully understood last sentence, could you please give me an example?

Comment: When you treat unchecked exceptions and the exception type represented by `CE` differently, it implies that `CE` must be a checked exception. But in principle you can invoke the `checked` method with a function which doesn’t throw any checked exception at all and let the compiler infer an unchecked exception type for `CE` as the declaration is `CE extends Throwable`, but then it doesn’t work. Unfortunately, the fact that `CE` must be a checked exception can’t be declared with the current state of Generics and the legacy exception type hierarchy.

Comment: Well said, @Holger, +1.  With unchecked exceptions being rethrown, there are no more worries, because the compiler will prevent any checked exception other than the expected one from being thrown.

Comment: @Holger, agree with @Hank D compiler will prevent throwing any other checked exceptions from method that aren't declared in `throws`. But if method can throw more than one checked exception or we will use couple of methods with different exceptions `CE` will be Throwable. Also if you call method with unchecked exception only `CE` will be `RuntimeException`.